# Problems while resizing bootable external drive :-(

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, external-hdd

Gparted hangs while trying to resize the existing ext4 bootable partion. How should I resize it to hold another partition for Windows ?

In more details, I had made the 1TB external drive bootable (Ubuntu 14.04) by using `dd` and copying a usb boot disk, which was 4 gb. Once the copying was done, I had used Gparted and merged the unused partition into the bootable partion.

Now, while resizing the ext4 partion (977gb), the Gparted hangs with the full error [here](http://justpaste.it/p3j8).

I assume the important points would be:

```
GParted 0.18.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 2.3
Shrink /dev/sdc1 from 929.55 GiB to 637.67 GiB  00:00:19    ( ERROR )

    calibrate /dev/sdc1  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

        path: /dev/sdc1
        start: 2048
        end: 1949403135
        size: 1949401088 (929.55 GiB)

    check file system on /dev/sdc1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:18    ( SUCCESS )

    e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sdc1

        Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
        Pass 2: Checking directory structure
        Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
        Pass 4: Checking reference counts
        Pass 5: Checking group summary information
        Error reading block 337 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading inode and block bitmaps. 
        Ignore error? yes

        Force rewrite? yes

        Error reading block 353 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading inode and block bitmaps. 
        Ignore error? yes

        Force rewrite? yes

        Error reading block 338 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading inode and block bitmaps. 
        Ignore error? yes

        Force rewrite? yes
...
```

and

```
        Force rewrite? yes

        Block bitmap differences: +(0--8605) +(8607--8664) +(8674--8700)
        +(9453--9455) +(9486--9738) +9741 +(9744--10337) +(10340--10479) 
        +(10482--10517) +(10520--10543) +(10592--10599) +(10664--10671) 
        +(10688--10724) +(10774--10775) +10846 +10848 +(10871--10872) 
        +(10936--10937) +11017 +11020 +(11047--11048) +(11101--11102) 
        +11173 +11175 +(11198--11236) +(11238--11256) +(11309--11310) 
        +11381 +11383 +(11406--11420) +(11473--11474) +11545 +11547 
        +(11570--11571) +(11624--11625) +11696 +11698 +(11721--11723) 
        +(11776--11777) +11848 +11850 +(11874--11886) +(11890--11900) 
        +(11902--11942) +11944 +(11946--12090) +(12103--12121) 
        +(12174--12175) +12246 +12248 +(12271--12295) +(12299--12351) 
        +12353 +(12355--12500) +(12513--12532) +(12585--12586) +12657 
        +12659 +(12682--12701) +(12705--12740) +(12747--12755) 
        +(12808--12809) +12880 +12882 +(12905--12908) +(12910--12923) 
        +(12927--12940) +(12942--13005) +(13007--13166) +(13182--13266) 
        +(13319--13320) +13391 +13393 +(13427--13439) +(13441--13453) 
        +(13457--13469) +(13471--13527) +(13529--13675) +(13684--13763) 
        +(13816--13817) +13888 +13890 +(13913--13929) +(14014--14015) 
        +14116 +14119 +(14149--14150) +(14235--14236) +14337 +14340 
        +(14371--14376) +(14380--14387) +(14392--14416) +14418 
        +(14427--14442) +(14527--14528) +14629 +14632 +(14662--14666) 
        +(14668--14680) +(14684--14696) +(14698--14718) +(14720--14745) 
        +14747 +(14749--14906) +(14919--14974) +(15027--15028) +15099 
        +15101 +(15124--15138) +(15191--15192) +15263 +15265 
...
```

with the similar message repeated many, many, MANY times.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

---

EDITED

@Fabby With the External HDD mounted, I get the following

```
maan@maan-Inspiron:/$ sudo smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdc -d sat # /dev/sdc [SAT], ATA device
maan@maan-Inspiron:/$
```

---

@adadion Yea, kind of ...  I had tried using Gpart with the USBLive mode, but I keep getting "Could not unmount" (?)

I had formatted the USB Stick with full version of Ubuntu, but as it was way to slow to do anything, I copied the usbs' into the external HDD.

To be more precise, I had done

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1
```

to copy the usb stick into the External HDD.

---

UPDATE 2

@Fabby I posted the output of `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb` in http://paste.ubuntu.com/13560861/

I assume it should not matter -- at present, the external HDD is mounted in `/var/sdb` so I used

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb
```

Comment: While reading [this](http://justpaste.it/p3j8), it feels odd with the last line information. `No such file or directory while opening /dev/sdc1`. Have you tried with gparted in LiveUSB mode? I know, it probably not making any differences since I guess the external HD are not your current running OS. But, it will be better to try, I guess.

Comment: You're doing an on-line resize: try doing an off-line one first.  Furthermore, your disk itself seems to have hardware problems (error reading block).  Please provide the output of `sudo smartctl --scan` so we can then do a deeper probe of the health of your disks.

Comment: @adadion I have added the response I am getting. Is this it what you were looking ?

Comment: @Fabby I have added the response I am getting. Is this it what you were looking ?

Comment: Yeah, can you provide the output of `smartctl --all /dev/sdc` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back into your question?